# Passing json data from one jsp to another in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide, liferay-aui

I am new to liferay and ended up failing to send data from one jsp to other. Below is my use case.

1. I have created 2 JSP files: first.jsp and second.jsp
2. I have created a href in first.jsp and on clicking of that, I am
   loading second.jsp by calling a renderURL.
3. All I want to achieve is that I am constructing a JSON data in
   first.jsp and when I click the href tag, I need to pass this json
   data to second.jsp file.

Any pointers on how to achieve this task would be appreciated?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this question doesn't show enough research. However, if you still don't want people to vote it down, elaborate the question. Provide details like: Why JSON? Won't render URL parameters work? Do you want to post them using AJAX call? etc.

Comment: I can research on it if I knew what to research for :) As i said im new to liferay, I am finding it difficult. 
Let me try to elaborate. JSON is not mandatory, I just used it as an example. All I want is just to pass some data from first.jsp to second.jsp, I tried with request.setAttribute("key",data) in first.jsp and then request.getAttribute(key) in second.jsp. But Im getting null as the data.

Comment: cool. Thanks . But I believe it is a site where one can interact with other EXPERIENCED developers when  struggling on an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to send the data by creating a renderURL in javascript code as show below. Posting it so that it might help someone like me out there :)

In first.jsp:-

```
<script>
AUI().ready('liferay-portlet-url', function(A) {
                 var renderURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
                 renderURL.setParameter("jspPage","/html/testsample/testsamplepage.jsp");
                 renderURL.setPortletId("testsamplepage_WAR_testsamplepageportlet");
                 renderURL.setParameter("rowData",data);
                 window.location.href = renderURL;
</script>
```

Then in second.jsp:-

```
<%
System.out.println(request.getParameter("rowData"));
%>
```